# Maui platform specific class library

Tags: c#, android, cross-platform, maui

I'm currently looking at Maui as the replacement for Xamarin Forms.
I currently have an Android class library for the Camera2 api that I would like to reuse.
How can I set up a Maui project that includes platform dependent class libraries?
So that when building and Android version I use the Android version of the class library. When building for Window I get the Windows version and IOS, I get the IOS version.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.
A Maui class library appears to be divided into platform specific sections plus a common section. So it appears I put the platform related code into the specific platform section and interface through the common section.

Comment: This is the default. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/single-project#platform-specific-code

You can also modify the csproj to allow platform specific targets by file or folder name (e.g. foo.Android.cs or src/Android/foo.cs ) as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting

Answer (score 0):

Use conditions in your cs project like this. It means the library is only compiled for Android.

```
    <ItemGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">
        <ProjectReference Include="..\AndroidLib1\AndroidLib1.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
```